# dynamique form added by javascript in div

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamique form added by javascript in div by its id but the problem is when i call this function to fill my div the first one call work fine but the second it added same input that already exist.then in the same div i have duplicate input

```
getAllPiece();

function getAllPiece(){
    $.getJSON(
         "getAllPiece", 
 {piece: $('select#typeevenement').val()},
 function(data) {
      var html = '';
      for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
          html += '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="piece" name="piece" value="'+data[i].codePiece+'" id="copiercin"/>' + data[i].libellePiece + '</label></div>';
          console.log(html);
       }
      $('#divpiece').append(html);
     }
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's nothing else in that `"#divpiece"` element you can use `html()` method instead `append()`, as it deletes also the content of the element you're adding your html to. So it would look like:

```
...
function(data) {
  var html = '';
  for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
      html += '<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" class="piece" name="piece" value="'+data[i].codePiece+'" id="copiercin"/>' + data[i].libellePiece + '</label></div>';
      console.log(html);
   }
  $("#divpiece").html(html); // HERE IS THE CHANGE
 }
);
```

if you need to append (if there's more than just the element you're adding) you have 2 possible solutions:

1. check if the `"#divpiece"` already has the element inside itself, like so `if($(".piece").val() === data[i].codePiece) { // stop script }`
2. if the div you append (`"<div class="checkbox">...</div>`) is unqiue, you can delete the whole div with `$("div.checkbox").remove()` and then add another one